# Json file could not read

Tags: gcloud

Could not read json file when running the gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/usr/sapSID/Home/3423.json

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

it should read the json file and service account is ok

Answer (score 0):

Re-create the json file and it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).